To print the elements of a do-loop, one after the other and not in column
If I do
reset session
# n = *some integer*. For simplicity, let's take n = 2
n = 2
array med2[n]
med2[1] = 3.23; med2[2] = 5.43
print 'MEDIA  '
do for [i=1:n]  {
print gprintf("%8.2f",med2[i])
}

I obtain
MEDIA
3.23
5.43
Is there a way to have them written one beside the other? That is
MEDIA   3.23    5.43
For n = 2, being so few, there's no need, but I have instead n = 12

I'm only aware of an indirect way, namely: to dump the values of the do-loop in a string:
reset session
# n = *some integer*. For simplicity, let's take n = 2
n = 2
array med2[n]
med2[1] = 3.23; med2[2] = 5.43
s = 'MEDIA  '
do for [i=1:n]  {
s = s.gprintf("%8.2f",med2[i])
}
print s

Result:
MEDIA      3.23    5.43
I guess there may be a more direct way, like putting some symbol right after 'MEDIA  ' and after the print in the loop. But I've got no idea.

It would help to know what the larger goal is.  I can provide a rather silly script that creates a 1-line file with values in a fixed format, but this solution is likely not easy to expand to handle a more complicated use case for which this is a minimal description.
# Load random numbers into an array of size N
N = 12
array A[N]
do for [i = 1:|A|] { A[i] = rand(0) }

unset key
unset border
unset tics
set margins 0,0,0,0
set xrange [10 : 10*(N+1)]    # 10 pixels (character cells) per array entry

# width of output is sufficient to hold N strings in format %6.4f
set term dumb size 10*(N+1), 1
set output "one_line_file.txt"

plot A using ($1*10):(0):(sprintf("%6.4f", $2)) with labels left

unset output

This produces output
$ cat one_line_file.txt

0.2225     0.1333     0.5360    0.8257     0.0780     0.9811     0.5678    0.5160     0.2370     0.6624     0.2281    0.6764      


I should write monthly mean values of meteo parameters all in a row (under another row with the name of the months but that's straightforward). So all of those 12 values are printed in a .txt file (there's a plot too :) but that's easy) one AFTER the other and not in column. Then, for the next year, the same story in a following row. And so on. Then at the end I should write the mean values of each month averaged to all of those years. That makes a new row with12 values. All one after the other, not in column. I thought maybe a symbol placed after the print statement would do the work, but not
